# UIPickerView under empty selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

When my `UIPickerView` View is empty *[the array is loads the data from is empty]*, If I try to select the Picker View the application crashes. What is the solution

Comment: What is in the crash log?

Comment: do not open picker when array is empty

Comment: you question has the answer into it...if ur array doesn't have any objects into it,then disable the click event on the picker view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but i guess that  error generated because your array is empty and you should write any where in delegate method of `UIPickerView` such like `[array objectAtindex....];` so,,

In each statement which you write `[array objectAtindex....];` put condition that

```
if(array.count > 0)
  [array objectAtindex....];..
```

So your picker will open but not generate any error.

**EDITED:**

I got solution for you:

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if ([myArray count] == 0)
        return 1;
    return [myArray count];
}
```

No need to apply any other condition i was checked it, in my project.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to array out of bound exception it seems. 
Check whether you are using any static index value while selecting the values.

e.g `[sourceArray objectAtIndex:0];` // It get crash when the source array is empty.